# How to show a badges count of ToolBarItem Icon in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

It is not about how to show notification badges nor it's about to show toolbar item icon. It is clear question that how to show a badges count on a toolbar item icon. ?

I am sharing code to create ToolbarItem with icon in XF content page:

In cs File:

```
    ToolbarItem cartItem = new ToolbarItem();
    scanItem.Text = "My Cart";
    scanItem.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary;
    scanItem.Icon = "carticon.png";

    ToolbarItems.Add(cartItem );
```

In Xaml File:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Cart" Priority="0" x:Name="menu1"> 
    </ToolbarItem>   
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Now I want to Place a badge count on the above added tool bar item icon. How it can be achieved ?

Comment: You can't do it from Forms directly. I know iOS has it built-in, not sure about Android

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes, you are right. iOS has feature to add badges, but android doesn't. I am stuck to create in Android as it same as in iOS.

Comment: This tutorial has exactly what you need: https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/08/adding-badge-to-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @AjaySharma even i need to place shopping cart icon...can you please tel me how you have achieved  ?

Answer (score 3):

Placing badge icon's in the native toolbars is actually more effort than its worth. If I need a badge icon, I remove the navigation page.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(myPageInstance, false);
```

Then I create my own toolbar from scratch. In this toolbar, I can overlay an image in there, you can also place a number in it as needed. For example.

```
 <Grid>           
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding IconCommand}" />
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

        <iconize:IconImage
                     Icon="fa-drawer"
                     IconColor="white"
                     IconSize="20" />

        <Grid Margin="15,-15,0,0">
            <iconize:IconImage Grid.Row="0"
                       HeightRequest="40"
                       WidthRequest="40"
                       Icon="fa-circle"
                       IconColor="red"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsCircleVisible}"
                       IconSize="10" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

I use [Iconize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize) wtih FontAwesome for the icons

Comment: Thanks for answer, no doubt this may be a good way to do this. There are more several way to achieve this. But I strictly want to do same with toolbarItem that is why I am posting this question.

Comment: @AdamPedley once you have that grid, how did you get that into your toolbar?  And then to place the number in the circle you would just use the Margin to overlay the number on the "fa-circle"?

Comment: I don't use the toolbar, I just place a Grid at the top of the page, and create my own toolbar. The inbuilt Xamarin.Forms one at the moment, is a real pain to extend beyond basic functionality.

Comment: Hi Adam, is that Iconize increasing project size and if it slows down startup time in Android?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Xamarin Forum Discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77099/toolbaritem-icon-with-badges-could-be-possible-and-with-custom-icon-too/p1?new=1), I have achieved it. Read ad understand the complete discussion before implement it. Thank you "Slava Chernikoff", "Emanuele Sabetta", "Mirza Sikander", "Satish" to discuss and yours share code.

Setp 1: Create a Helper Class in PCL and install NGraphics package from nugget.

```
 public class CartIconHelper
{
    private static Graphic _svgGraphic = null;
    public const string ResourcePath = "ToolBarAndroidBadge.Resources.cartIcon.svg";

    private static PathOp[] RoundRect(NGraphics.Rect rect, double radius)
    {
        return new PathOp[]
                   {
                   new NGraphics.MoveTo(rect.X + radius, rect.Y),
                   new NGraphics.LineTo(rect.X + rect.Width - radius, rect.Y),
                   new NGraphics.ArcTo(new NGraphics.Size(radius, radius), true, false, new NGraphics.Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + radius)),
                   new NGraphics.LineTo(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height - radius),
                   new NGraphics.ArcTo(new NGraphics.Size(radius, radius), true, false, new NGraphics.Point(rect.X + rect.Width - radius, rect.Y + rect.Height)),
                   new NGraphics.LineTo(rect.X + radius, rect.Y + rect.Height),
                   new NGraphics.ArcTo(new NGraphics.Size(radius, radius), true, false, new NGraphics.Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - radius)),
                   new NGraphics.LineTo(rect.X, rect.Y + radius), new NGraphics.ArcTo(new NGraphics.Size(radius, radius), true, false, new NGraphics.Point(rect.X + radius, rect.Y)),
                   new NGraphics.ClosePath()
                   };
    }

    public static string DrawCartIcon(int count, string path, double iconSize = 30, double scale = 2, string fontName = "Arial", double fontSize = 12, double textSpacing = 4)
    {
        var service = DependencyService.Get<IService>();

        var canvas = service.GetCanvas();

        if (_svgGraphic == null) using (var stream = typeof(CartIconHelper).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
                _svgGraphic = new SvgReader(new StreamReader(stream)).Graphic; 
                 //st = ReadFully(stream);

        var minSvgScale = Math.Min(canvas.Size.Width / _svgGraphic.Size.Width, canvas.Size.Height / _svgGraphic.Size.Height) / 1.15;

        var w = _svgGraphic.Size.Width / minSvgScale;
        var h = _svgGraphic.Size.Height / minSvgScale;

        _svgGraphic.ViewBox = new NGraphics.Rect(0, -14, w, h);
        _svgGraphic.Draw(canvas);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            var text = count > 99 ? "99+" : count.ToString();
            var font = new NGraphics.Font(fontName, fontSize);
            var textSize = canvas.MeasureText(text, font);

            var textRect = new NGraphics.Rect(canvas.Size.Width - textSize.Width - textSpacing, textSpacing, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);

            if (count < 10)
            {
                var side = Math.Max(textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
                var elipseRect = new NGraphics.Rect(canvas.Size.Width - side - 2 * textSpacing, 0, side + 2 * textSpacing, side + 2 * textSpacing);
                canvas.FillEllipse(elipseRect, NGraphics.Colors.Red);
                textRect -= new NGraphics.Point(side - textSize.Width, side - textSize.Height) / 2.0;
            }
            else
            {
                var elipseRect = new NGraphics.Rect(textRect.Left - textSpacing, textRect.Top - textSpacing, textRect.Width + 2 * textSpacing, textSize.Height + 2 * textSpacing);
                canvas.FillPath(RoundRect(elipseRect, 6), NGraphics.Colors.Red);
            }
            var testReact1= new NGraphics.Rect(20,12,0,0);
            // canvas.DrawText(text, textRect + new NGraphics.Point(0, textSize.Height), font, NGraphics.TextAlignment.Center, NGraphics.Colors.Black);
            canvas.DrawText("5", testReact1, font, NGraphics.TextAlignment.Left, NGraphics.Colors.White);

        }

        service.SaveImage(canvas.GetImage());
        string imagePath = service.GetImage();
        return imagePath;
       // return st;
    }

}
```

Step 2: Create a interface to IService in PCL

```
 public interface IService
{
    IImageCanvas GetCanvas();
    void SaveImage(NGraphics.IImage image);
    string GetImage();
}
```

Step 3 : Implement this interface in your Android project

```
 class CanvasServices:IService
{
        private readonly AndroidPlatform _platform;
        public CanvasServices()
        {
            _platform = new AndroidPlatform();
        }

        public void SaveImage(IImage image)
        {
        var dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "cart.png");
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        image.SaveAsPng(stream);
        //bitmap.Compress(image., 100, stream);
        stream.Close();
    }

        public string GetImage()
        {
            var dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "cart.png");
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
            return filePath;
        }

        public IImageCanvas GetCanvas()
        {
            NGraphics.Size size = new NGraphics.Size(30);
            return _platform.CreateImageCanvas(size);
        }

        public NGraphics.AndroidPlatform GetPlatform()
        {
            return _platform;
        }
}
```

Setp 4: Now, use CartIcon Helper in your PCL project to show badges in TabBarItem.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var imagePath = CartIconHelper.DrawCartIcon(2, "ToolBarAndroidBadge.Resources.cartIcon.svg");
        string deviceSepecificFolderPath = Device.OnPlatform(null, imagePath, null);
        object convertedObject = new FileImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromInvariantString(deviceSepecificFolderPath);
        FileImageSource fileImageSource = (FileImageSource)convertedObject;                

        ToolbarItem cartItem = new ToolbarItem();
        cartItem.Text = "My Cart";
        cartItem.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary;
        cartItem.Icon = fileImageSource;




        ToolbarItems.Add(cartItem);

    }
}
```

Comment: What about iOS? How to implement?

Comment: @rraallvv -  I am having minimum working experience in Xamarin but having enough experience in .NET. May I know why are you asking this ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement below code to draw a ground circle with text over toolbar icon

1. BarButtonItemExtensions.cs

```
using CoreAnimation;    
using CoreGraphics;    
using Foundation;    
using ObjCRuntime;    
using System;    
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UIKit;

namespace TeamCollaXform.Views.Services
{
    public static class BarButtonItemExtensions
    {
        enum AssociationPolicy
        {
            ASSIGN = 0,
            RETAIN_NONATOMIC = 1,
            COPY_NONATOMIC = 3,
            RETAIN = 01401,
            COPY = 01403,
        }

        static NSString BadgeKey = new NSString(@"BadgeKey");

        [DllImport(Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary)]
        static extern void objc_setAssociatedObject(IntPtr obj, IntPtr key, IntPtr value, AssociationPolicy policy);


        [DllImport(Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary)]
        static extern IntPtr objc_getAssociatedObject(IntPtr obj, IntPtr key);

        static CAShapeLayer GetBadgeLayer(UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem)
        {
            var handle = objc_getAssociatedObject(barButtonItem.Handle, BadgeKey.Handle);

            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var value = ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(handle);
                if (value != null)
                    return value as CAShapeLayer;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void DrawRoundedRect(CAShapeLayer layer, CGRect rect, float radius, UIColor color, bool filled)
        {
            layer.FillColor = filled ? color.CGColor : UIColor.White.CGColor;
            layer.StrokeColor = color.CGColor;
            layer.Path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(rect, radius).CGPath;
        }

        public static void AddBadge(this UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem, string text, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor textColor, bool filled = true, float fontSize = 11.0f)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return;
            }

            CGPoint offset = CGPoint.Empty;

            if (backgroundColor == null)
                backgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

            var font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize);

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(9, 0))
            {
                font = UIFont.MonospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(fontSize, UIFontWeight.Regular);
            }

            var view = barButtonItem.ValueForKey(new NSString(@"view")) as UIView;
            var bLayer = GetBadgeLayer(barButtonItem);
            bLayer?.RemoveFromSuperLayer();


            var badgeSize = text.StringSize(font);


            var height = badgeSize.Height;
            var width = badgeSize.Width + 5; /* padding */

            //make sure we have at least a circle
            if (width < height)
            {
                width = height;
            }

            //x position is offset from right-hand side
            var x = view.Frame.Width - width + offset.X;


            var badgeFrame = new CGRect(new CGPoint(x: x - 4, y: offset.Y + 5), size: new CGSize(width: width, height: height));

            bLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
            DrawRoundedRect(bLayer, badgeFrame, 7.0f, backgroundColor, filled);
            view.Layer.AddSublayer(bLayer);

            // Initialiaze Badge's label
            var label = new CATextLayer();
            label.String = text;
            label.TextAlignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.Center;
            label.SetFont(CGFont.CreateWithFontName(font.Name));
            label.FontSize = font.PointSize;
            label.Frame = badgeFrame;
            label.ForegroundColor = filled ? textColor.CGColor : UIColor.White.CGColor;
            label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
            label.ContentsScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
            bLayer.AddSublayer(label);

            // Save Badge as UIBarButtonItem property
            objc_setAssociatedObject(barButtonItem.Handle, BadgeKey.Handle, bLayer.Handle, AssociationPolicy.RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

        }
        public static void UpdateBadge(this UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem, string text, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor textColor)
        {
            var bLayer = GetBadgeLayer(barButtonItem);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text == "0")
            {
                bLayer?.RemoveFromSuperLayer();

                objc_setAssociatedObject(barButtonItem.Handle, BadgeKey.Handle, new CAShapeLayer().Handle, AssociationPolicy.ASSIGN);
                return;
            }

            var textLayer = bLayer?.Sublayers?.First(p => p is CATextLayer) as CATextLayer;
            if (textLayer != null)
            {
                textLayer.String = text;
            }
            else
            {
                barButtonItem.AddBadge(text, backgroundColor, textColor);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

2. ToolbarItemBadgeService.cs

```
using TeamCollaXform.Views.Services; 
using Xamarin.Forms; 
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ToolbarItemBadgeService))] 
namespace TeamCollaXform.Views.Services 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public interface IToolbarItemBadgeService
    {
        void SetBadge(Page page, ToolbarItem item, string value, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class ToolbarItemBadgeService : IToolbarItemBadgeService
    {
        public void SetBadge(Page page, ToolbarItem item, string value, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(page);
                if (renderer == null)
                {
                    renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(page);
                    Platform.SetRenderer(page, renderer);
                }
                var vc = renderer.ViewController;

                var rightButtomItems = vc?.ParentViewController?.NavigationItem?.RightBarButtonItems;
                var idx = rightButtomItems.Length - page.ToolbarItems.IndexOf(item) - 1;            //Revert

                if (rightButtomItems != null && rightButtomItems.Length > idx)
                {
                    var barItem = rightButtomItems[idx];
                    if (barItem != null)
                    {
                        barItem.UpdateBadge(value, backgroundColor.ToUIColor(), textColor.ToUIColor());
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    } 
}
```

3. Usage

```
    void OnAttachClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var answer = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
        //Debug.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer);

        ToolbarItem cmdItem = sender as ToolbarItem;

        DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, cmdItem, $"2", Color.DarkOrange, Color.White);
    }
```

Links: 1) for instruction and 2) for sample code

1. https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/08/adding-badge-to-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/
2. https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ToolbarItemBadgeSample

Answer (score 1):

For any one who wants to add badge on toolbar item using custom ui try, 
Instead of using default toolbar item, you can hide the default navigation bar by `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`
in the constructor.

Then prepare the custom navigation bar with toolbar item with badge as mentioned in above answers.

If you are using master detail page, hiding default navigation bar will hide hamburger icon, so need to slide from left to see sliding menu. Alternate method would be place a button with hamburger icon in custom navigation bar, on button click use messaging center to present the sliding menu.

Example: On page in which hamburger button is clicked

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "presnt");           
        }
```

On MasterDetail page

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<YourPage>(this, "presnt", (sender) =>
            {
                IsPresented = true;
            });
```

Before making `IsPresented=true`, check for sliding menu is not all-ready presented.

Check https://github.com/LeslieCorrea/Xamarin-Forms-Shopping-Cart for badge on toolbar item.