# Remove padding/margin on Xamarin Forms AppShell titlebar (toolbar)

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-toolbar, app-shell

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out using all kinds of fixes i found on SO and other sites but to no avail...

I'm using AppShell and I can't get the padding/margin next to the hamburger button to go away.

[image: toolbar padding/margin]

As you can see, next to the hamburger button there is extra padding or margin but i don't think it belongs to the TitleView (the black is a view that i use, it's black to show the boundaries).

[image: OnCreate function]

In my OnCreate function i already have the `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;`

[image: Toolbar.xml]

In Toolbar.xml i added `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

and `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"  app:contentInsetStart="0dp"  app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829018/remove-left-space-in-title-view-xamarin-forms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990741/how-to-remove-left-space-in-toolbar-and-above-and-under) but those seem to be solutions for NavigationPage, but i don't use that in AppShell.

Help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I created a CustomRenderer for the AppShell to see if that would make a difference.

[image: Used functions]

[image: breakpoint]

but as you can see only the ContentInsetEndWithActions and ContentInsetStartWithNavigation actually get set to 0. The other ones remain 32 so they obviously ignore the Toolbar.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

In the MainActivity replace this code: [image]

this in combination with the CustomRenderer made it work finally...