# Xamarin Forms Remove SHELL Navigation Bar Left Padding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigationbar, xamarin.shell

This question is similar to these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829018/remove-left-space-in-title-view-xamarin-forms), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580177/xamarin-forms-navigationbar-has-left-margin), & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990741/how-to-remove-left-space-in-toolbar-and-above-and-under)) questions, but none of their solutions solve my problem.

The issue is the same, I need to remove the left padding in the `TitleView`, shown below:

[image: Navbar with left padding]

I have created a custom `Toolbar` layout defined as:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"/>
```

And I have set the `ToolbarResource` to `Resource.Layout.Toolbar` before calling `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` in my `MainActivity.cs`. The padding is still there.

> `<NavigationPage.TitleView> ... </NavigationPage.TitleView>`

It seems that the custom `Toolbar` layout does not override the `Shell`'s navigation bar but `NavigationPage`s. I am using `Shell.TitleView`.

Does anyone know how to override and remove the padding from `Shell`'s navigation bar?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve These are two *different* Navigation paradigms. `Shell` provides a different Navigation paradigm as was available with `NavigationPage`, defining my `MainPage` as `NavigationPage` creates a navigation bar without the padding. As I mentioned previously I am using `Shell`, and it's navigation bar still has the padding which I am struggling to override.

Comment: My apologies, I did not read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CustomShellRenderer to get the toolbar of the shellpage and set the properties. Such as the following code.

MyShellRenderer.cs

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App9.ShellTest), 
typeof(App9.Droid.MyShellRenderer))]
namespace App9.Droid
{
    internal class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }
}
```

MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace App9.Droid
{
    public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : 
ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context) : 
base(context)
    {
    }

        public override void ResetAppearance(AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker)
        {
            base.ResetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker);
            toolbar.SetContentInsetsRelative(0, 0);
            toolbar.ContentInsetStartWithNavigation = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this renderer, but there is no change to the padding in `Shell`s nav bar. Setting some breakpoints showed that the class was initialized but the override for `ResetAppearance` was never hit.

Comment: In the offical document, the example overrides the SetAppearance method and I have tried but it wasn't hit. So I override the ResetAppearance. You can try to override the SetAppearance method. There is the link about the offical document.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers)@MuhammadKhan